# Problem with using \epstopdfsetup command

Tags: fonts, pdftex, epstopdf, embedding, ieeeconf

I am trying to convert eps figure (generated by Matlab) to PDF. The goal is to attach the figure to a conference paper for publication. As many others have pointed out, Matlab generate eps files with non-embedded fonts and as a result IEEE does not accept the PDF. I have been looking to solve this issue for a couple of days.

I have tried using epstopdf package which generates a PDF but when I tried to upload the paper, IEEE still does not allow due to the font issue. I have been trying to edit the options of the epstopdf package by changing

Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass[]{report}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Main report}
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext

\appendix
\chapter{Parametric study}
\clearpage

\epstopdfsetup{-dEmbedAllFonts=true} 

\section{Subset A}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{ICC.eps}
\caption{Parametric study - subset A.}
\label{fig:A-example}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

This gives me a "Undefined control sequence" error. I have already checked my Pdflatex option as recommended by others: "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex" is set already.

My problems are: how can I use \epstopdfsetup option inside a latex file? and how can I use \epstopdfsetup to generate a PDF from eps that will solve the non-embedded font issue. Thanks so much.

Comment: Imho epstopdf (the programm not the package) already uses the embed option. You should at first try on the command line if `epstopdf file` or `epstopdf --embed file`  gets you are correct pdf.

Comment: I am using Texmaker. Where should I run this command? Thanks.

Comment: You should run it in console. However, it seems there are some issues with 32-bit MiKTeX: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/296. As @UlrikeFischer mentioned, fonts should be embedded by default, but they are not.

Comment: Hi, are you maybe using MiKTeX installed "for all users"?

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer. Do you understand this issue https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/386?